# crystal report from dataset in c# has a lot of spaces on string fields

Tags: crystal-reports

when creating crystal report from dataset in c# , some times the data in string fields appears not aligned and it seems have a lot of spaces before the text value .
please how can I remove all this spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Trim` function.

```
Trim(String database field)
```